# How to divide a date column in two columns only

Tags: r, date, data.table, lubridate

I have a data frame containing 1 date column:

```
> head(df$date)
[1] "1952-02-03" "1958-02-08" "1958-02-08" "1958-02-08" "1965-02-07" "1966-03-03"
```

The format is as you can see: "Y%-m%-d%"

I want to create two columns from this one, one containing the Years only and the second one containing the month and the day together.

**Output wanted**

| year | month_day |
| --- | --- |
| 1952 | 02-03 |
| 1958 | 02-08 |

and so on.

I tried this:

```
setDT(df)[, c("year", "month_day") := 
         c(tstrsplit(date, "-", type.convert = TRUE))]
```

but of course I get this error message: `Supplied 2 columns to be assigned 3 items.`
which I fully understand but I cannot find anywhere the syntax to split only in two columns the date information.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `format` to get the parts of the date you want:

```r
df$year  <- format(df$date, "%Y")
df$month_day  <- format(df$date, "%m-%d")

df

#         date year month_day
# 1 1952-02-03 1952     02-03
# 2 1958-02-08 1958     02-08
# 3 1958-02-08 1958     02-08
# 4 1958-02-08 1958     02-08
# 5 1965-02-07 1965     02-07
# 6 1966-03-03 1966     03-03
```

Comment: thanks, by any chance do you know how to convert the output columns to a date class object? `> class(df$month_day)
[1] "character"` vs `> class(df$date)
[1] "Date"`

Comment: The problem is that they're not dates. If you want them to be of `Date` class they will need to be a valid date, i.e. have a year, month and day, even if you know they're just dummies. You could do something for year `as.Date(format(df$date, "%Y-01-01"))` which will produce `1952-01-01` and so on for each year. What operation do you need to do that requires them to be split, and also to be a `Date`?

Comment: I want to perform the following operation, which consists of calculating the median day/month of a phenomena by degree of latitude and by decade: `df_median = df %>% group_by(lat, decade) %>% summarise(across(month_day, median)) %>% ungroup`  but it gives this error right now: Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(month_day, median)`.
Caused by error:
! `month_day` must return compatible vectors across groups.
i Result type for group 1 (lat = 55, decade = "1950-1959"): <double>.
i Result type for group 2 (lat = 55, decade = "1960-1969"): <character>

Comment: But the code runs if I replace `month_day` by `date` in `summarise` (it just does not give the wanted output) and what has changed between `month_day` and `date` is the class I think.

Comment: I don't know what's causing that error but I don't think the issue is to do with it being a `character` vector rather than `Date`. It doesn't look right to me that you're using `across` with only one column. It might be worth posting as a separate question with some minimal sample data.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice and the answers, I will look deeper into it and post a question if I do not manage to solve it :)